# What is the best practice to calculate a hash on a BufferedImage?

Tags: java, hash, bufferedimage

I am working on a program that processes images, and can flip them if the underlying OCR detects that they are upside down.
However the OCR output is not 100% reliable in terms of bounding boxes, so sometimes it is wrongly detected that an invoice is upside down... forever.

I need to prevent this: The files have no unique identifiers anymore after they've been flipped, I can not see anymore that they are the same file after it has been flipped two times.

So what would be the best, or an acceptable, practice to create a hash from `BufferedImage`s. I assume that every time the same file has been read, it will generate also the same RGB values for every pixel in the `BufferedImage`.

I can implement some naive algorithm myself, taking the RGB of every pixel, and then computing a hash/checksum. However I do not believe this is a correct method, how would it be best to do it?

Comment: Generating a hash would loop over all the bytes; why not compare the actual pixels themselves if you must check for equal images?

Comment: @Gimby Because, I forgot to add, it needs to be stored in a database, hence a relative small size is preferred.

Comment: Could you not simply store which images are copies of each other then? I'm sticking to you only wanting to know which images are equal, a hash is a technical solution you're trying to marry to. A difficult one too because you need a hash which is guaranteed unique then.

Comment: @Gimby If hashes are not reliable, then I could try it... But it won't be easy. The proces of one file goes like: `random.pdf` -> `random.tiff` -> `1000.tiff` -> `1000-flipped.tiff` -> `1001.tiff` -> `1001-flipped.tiff` -> `1002.tiff`. That is kind of the renaming sequence.

Comment: I didn't say hashes are unreliable, but the common ones such as MD5 are not 100% clash-free. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5